# Resolving an array of Dependencies in Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have the following code, in which I register a series of types (also tried this with RegisterInstance):

```
container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>("Type1", new InjectionConstructor(1, "test");
container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>("Type2", new InjectionConstructor(2, "hello world");
```

I then inject this into a class like so:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private readonly IMyService[] _services;

    public MyClass(
        IMyService[] services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }
```

So far, so good.  However, at a later stage, I want to be able to retrieve the class by its name; for example:

```
_services["Type2"].DoStuff();
```

Since _services is an array, I need to reference it by it's index.  There are no properties inside IMyService that would allow me to pull the correct one using Linq.  I did entertain the idea of wrapping the class inside another class that does have such a property, but that seems like it should not be necessary.

Is there a way that Unity provides this kind of thing directly out of the box, or is there a nice way to do this that I haven't considered?

Comment: Why do you (think that you) need a service by name?

Comment: As you can see, the two classes are instantiated with different parameters.  As a result, I’m maintaining two distinct versions of the service (that is, because of the constructor parameters, they will behave differently from each other).

Comment: You don't write *why* you need to distinguish between two polymorphic objects, but in most cases, I recommend a [Partial Type Name Role Hint](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/11/PartialTypeNameRoleHint), although you might also find a [Role Interface Role Hint](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/10/RoleInterfaceRoleHint) useful, or perhaps even  [Metadata Role Hint](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/09/MetadataRoleHint).